# "Only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts" when making a convolution function in R

Tags: r, conv-neural-network

When I compute the convolution,I got the error "only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts".
I checked a few other answers about this it but they are not for my case.
This function is for getting the convolution.

```
convolution <- function(X,K){
  y <- matrix(nrow=nrow(X)-nrow(K)+1,ncol=ncol(X)-ncol(K)+1)
  for (i in 1:nrow(X)-nrow(K)+1){
    for (j in 1:ncol(X)-ncol(K)+1){
      y[i,j] <- sum(X[i:(i+nrow(K)-1),j:(j+ncol(K)-1)] * K)
    }
  }
  return(y)
}

convolution(X,K)
```

While X is a 4×4 matrix and K is 3×3 matrix. The convolution(X,K) should output a 2×2 matrix.
What can I do to get rid of the error.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you are just missing the brackets in the for-statements, e.g.:
for (i in 1: (nrow(X)-nrow(K)+1)))

Comment: @JKupzig Thank you! I fixed it~ The report mention "Error in X[i:((i + nrow(K) - 1)), j:((j + ncol(K) - 1))]" which made me ignored the problem from other code.